# How to write an instance for all types in another type class?

Tags: haskell

I have to define a type class `Truthy` which contains a method `true` converting an instance of the type class to a `Bool` value.

My type class declaration:

```
class Truthy a where
    true :: a -> Bool
```

Next, I have to define instances of this class for various types, including list and numeric types. I have done it for lists and `Int`s, but is there a way to do it for all numeric types at once?

Based on my Int declaration:

```
instance Truthy Int where
    true = (/=) 0
```

I have tried adding type class constraint, but it does not work:

```
instance (Num a) => (Truthy a) where
    true = (/=) 0::a
```

If there is a way to do this similar to what I had in mind, or should I just define it for each numeric type separately?

Comment: "or should I just define it for each numeric type separately?" - in a word **Yes**. The design goal of type classes is to allow overloading on a per-type basis. With extensions it can be possible to define "overreaching" instances but they are usually a design flaw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declare all instances of a typeclass are in another typeclass without modifying the original class declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461029/declare-all-instances-of-a-typeclass-are-in-another-typeclass-without-modifying)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might not help for homework, but you actually *can* write a declaration like that. You just have to enable `-XFlexibleInstances` to do so. At least in GHC, you can do this by putting a pragma at the top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
```

If you look closely at the error message you got, it said something like "Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.".

In this particular case, you would also need to enable `UndecidableInstances` and `OverlappingInstances`:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances,  UndecidableInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}
```

You need `FlexibleInstances` because standard Haskell does not allow instances in any form where the type variable appears more than once in the head. This is completely fine--I it is one of the most common extensions used (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826630/type-class-problem-concerning-flexibleinstances)).

You need `UndecidableInstances` because your instance declaration could potentially cause the type checker to loop forever. I think using `UndecidableInstances` prevents this by limiting how deeply it will check when trying to reduce the instance. This is usually--including in this case--fine, but could theoretically make whether a particular program passes the type checks *implementation dependent*. Still, it should work in your case.

As hammar pointed out, you need to enable `OverlappingInstances` because the "context" of the instance is *ignored* when checking whether they overlap. The context is the `Num a` bit in this case. So the instances--for checking if it overlaps--is read as `instance Truthy a...` and overlaps with everything. With `OverlappingInstances` enabled, you just need to have one instance that is the most specific for this to work.

Comment: I saw that in the error log. It would be great to get an explanation about why I need to enable anything extra in order to get this to compile, or at leas where I can read up on that. Also, is that the only way to do what I want?

Comment: Basically, the Haskell 98 report specified that class declarations have to be "simple". So *standard* Haskell does not allow the style you tried to use (unless it changed in 2010?). However, the code you wrote is actually reasonable and implementable, so it's supported by GHC; the reason you need the pragma is that it's not in the standard.

Comment: For more information than you probably want, you can read about it in the docs [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#superclass-rules) and [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#flexible-contexts).

Comment: UndecideableInstances just means that the compiler will allow instances that could potentially make the typechecker loop. I think the way it handles it is by limiting the number of recursions it allows when checking the type. [Here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#undecidable-instances) is the documentation for them.

Comment: Looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826630/type-class-problem-concerning-flexibleinstances) question, it seems your best option is to use `FlexibleInstances`. It's a completely reasonable thing to do and I don't think there is any alternative (short of declaring an instance for each type) in standard Haskell.

Comment: You will also need `OverlappingInstances` if you want any instances other than the one for numbers, since it overlaps with everything. This is because the instance head is `a` which matches anything. The `Num` constraint isn't checked until after.

Comment: @hammar: *Any* instances? I tried adding a trivial instance for `Bool` and it worked just with `FlexibleInstances` and `UndecideableInstances`. Is there something more complicated at play?

Comment: Also, are my reasons for the two instances broadly correct? I think they are, but I am not 100% certain.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: Defining the instances is fine, but have you tried actually using them?

Comment: Oh, good point. I guess I'm getting spoiled by having most of my errors caught at compile time :)